# Why aren't my While loops working correctly?

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, while-loop

I wonder if someone would be so kind as to tell me why my code is not working. Debugging shows that Value can equal 1 or 2, but VB will only execute the first while statement, never the second.

```
Const AnswerA As String = "Copenhagen"
Const AnswerB As String = "Peter the Great"
Dim Value As Integer
Dim Message, Response As String
Private Sub btnAskMe_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAskMe.Click
    Randomize()
    ' Generate random value between 1 and 2 to test only. 
    Value = CInt(Int((2 * Rnd()) + 1))
    If Value = 1 Then
        Message = "What's the capital of Denmark?"
        While Response <> AnswerA
            Response = InputBox(Message)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Response) Then Exit Sub
            If Response <> AnswerA Then Message = "No, no, no! Think boy, think?"
        End While
        MsgBox("Correct....What took you so long?")
    End If
    If Value = 2 Then
        Message = "Which Russian Tsar forced his wife to keep her lovers head in a jar?"
        While Response <> AnswerB
            Response = InputBox(Message)
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Response) Then Exit Sub
            If Response <> AnswerB Then Message = "No you twerp! Have another go"
        End While
        MsgBox("Correct....What took you so long?")
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Done **ANY** basic debugging, like checking if your function is actually called? Check what value is in `Value`? And exactly how do you expect your `Value = 2` code to runs ince you have an `Exit Sub` right above it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added the Exit Sub because I didn't want VB to run through the rest of the script once the first question had been answered correctly. My hope was that if the generator came up with 2, then the second question will show. I am new to VB so my debugging skills are limited, although I have tried Step Into.

Comment: Step Into shows that Value can = 1 or =2, but the code will only run the first While response. It never skips to the second even if the Value is 2. I would appreciate any further advice you might have to offer.

Comment: @Shog9 I hope my rephrased question is more clear. Being new to VB sometimes means that I lack the ability to express exactly what I mean - apologies.

Comment: For future reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a problem with your "end if" location
here

```
    If Value = 1 Then
        Message = "What's the capital of Denmark?"
    End If
```

and here

```
    If Value = 2 Then
        Message = "Which Russian Tsar forced his wife to keep her lovers head in a jar?"
    End If
```

the first end if needs to come after
the "Exit Sub" line
and the second after
the "End While"

Comment: Agreed, putting the End If after the Exit Sub seems like good sense. However, when I try this, my first Else statement gets a wiggly line and VB wants me to add an End IF.  Meanwhile, the End IF I moved as suggested also gets a wiggly line because it needs to start with an IF. Any ideas?

Comment: difficult for me to check your code. it does not compile on ms access 2003 which uses a slightly different visual basic dialect.i.e. to mark the end of a while loop  it uses "end" and not "end while" like yours. but my advice would be to  put both questions in the same while loop simplifying your code and getting rid of end sub, then you can use "continue while" insead of "exit sub" ."continue while" skips the rest of the code in the loop for current iteration and start over with the new iteration so it will have similar effect here. good luck!

Comment: @RickTicky - Making the change that `call me carrot` suggested should not have produced the errors you described.  Are you sure you _moved_ the `End If` statement rather than just copying it?  Are you sure you moved the correct `End If` statement?  Can you show your updated code?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion Call me carrot and Chris. I really appreciate the advice.. Will try to implement now.

Comment: @callmecarrot Can I thank you. I wasn't able to put both questions into the same while (but will continue to give it a whirl), but your suggestions got me thinking very carefully about how I was using them. It also encouraged me to use the 'watch' feature of Step Into. Without the kindness of you and Chris, I would not have had the tenacity to keep trying. How do I award your responses? I have put my working code above

Comment: @rickticky glad to see your code working! to put the things in a single while: change the the first  "While Response <> AnswerA" line to "While not ((Response = AnswerA and Value =1) or (Response = AnswerB and Value =2))" and move the resulting changed line just before  "If Value = 1 Then".then  remove the first   "End While" and the old "While Response <> AnswerB". But leave the last "end while" where it is. it may be a good start to play around and simplify your code.If you think it is appropriate you could accept my reply as the correct answer this will give me more credentials. Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

It'll never work properly:

```
    While ResponseB <> AnswerB
                  ^----check Response **B**
        ResponseA = InputBox(Message)
                ^---- get a response into Response **A**
```

Comment: Ahh..very well spotted. Many thanks Marc! That certainly doesn't help. I just wish I knew why the code gets stuck in the first while and never progresses to the second, even if the value is 2